# Overwriting Artifactory artifacts (and history)?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I'm currently trying to get a feel for [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) and playing around with deploying "generic" artifacts into a simple repo. (I'm using the web interface as well as a minimal Jenkins upload by [Upload File Spec](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds).)

What I see is that I can deploy an artifact under the same name/path more than once, e.g. I have the artifact `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/martin-repo/martin/bla/foo.zip` in my `martin-repo` and I can deploy this as often as I want and it will just *overwrite* it.

It will just list a

> - Created:    25-01-17 23:20:09 +01:00
> - Last Modified:  25-01-17 23:32:33
>     +01:00

for the artifact under `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/martin-repo/.../...`

#### Questions --

- **Is there some kind of history of different "versions" of an artifact in Artifactory?**
- Or is the old version just lost as soon as a new version under the same path is deployed?
- Is there any write-once option for a repository, so that each artifact path can by default only be uploaded once?

---

*Disclaimer*: I'm a total Noob here, so if I miss something, feel free to point out any RTFM.

From the examples I see, it seems normally one would include a version number in the path to be deployed, but as far as I can tell, the path would be "client"-generated, so the server has to have some handle on this also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there some kind of history of different "versions" of an artifact in Artifactory?**

*If I understand you correctly you mean something like in version control, to roll back to older files. If this is the case then the answer that this is not something that is available in Artifactory*

**Or is the old version just lost as soon as a new version under the same path is deployed?**

*Once a file is overridden, the old one is lost. Please note that overriding files, especially releases, considered bad practice.*

**Is there any write-once option for a repository, so that each artifact path can by default only be uploaded once?**

*The only option that you have will be to remove "Delete/Overwrite" permission to the users. Then, once they will try to write a file that already exist they will get the following error:*

```
{
    "errors" : [ {
        "status" : 403,
        "message" : "Not enough permissions to overwrite artifact 'XXX' (user 'YYY' needs DELETE permission)."
    } ]
}
```

Comment: Cheers. So wrt. "Delete/Overwrite" that would probably be the *default* to remove from any user, especially the user used from a build server, because as you say ... "Please note that overriding files, especially releases, considered bad practice."

Comment: So there's no `disable redeployment` in Artifactory? see e.g. http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/11/nexus-tips-disable-redeployment-in-nexus/ - I just Googled this. I think it's similar(?)

Comment: So it seems that the end action is the same.  As the "Delete/Overwrite" permission is not something that all the users have I believe that thats the way to go. As I mentioned, and the link of Sonatype also says the same, there is no reason to overwrite an artifact but you can release minor version instead.  In case of SNAPSHOTS you don't have thiz issue as Artifactory has the feature of "Max unique snapshots"  in the snapshot repository.